# How can I add attributes to all heading elements with jQuery?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**How to change the heading tags `<h1>` to `<h1 data-splitting>` and `<h2>` to `<h2 data-splitting>` and `<h3>` to `<h3 data-splitting>` and `<h4>` to `<h4 data-splitting>` in WordPress?**

How can I change them on all pages through hard coding or by change through JS/JQuery?

For hard coding, where should I look at, on theme files, or is it coded into the WordPress itself?

There are ID’s and classes such as `<div id="nav">` and `<div class="sidebar-box">` but what is the above type is called as? Is it same as `<h2>` + `<data-splitting>`?

This is required to add some animation effect to the headings - [View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/YOPqLb)

Now how can I change heading tags?

I added this to the WordPress fuctions.php:-

```
 function enqueue_my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hjs', 'https://example.com/h.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_script' );
```

The h.js has the following code:-

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

});
```

But this doesn't add the script to the head.

I even added it manually as `<script async src="https://example.com/h.js">` but it does **not** gets show up in the head

If I add any other script manually like `<script async src="https://example.com/a.js">` it **does** gets added.

I even tried to add the JS as inline in the head, now the script **does shows up in the head section as inline JS** but doesn't change the `<h1>` to `<h1 data-splitting>` and `<h2>` to `<h2 data-splitting>`.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

});
</script
```

or as

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {
    $('document').ready(function() {

        $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

    });
});
</script>
```

Now the script is present in the head as inline JS but it does change the heading tags.

Comment: Your script seems ok. If your problem is getting jQuery loading in WordPress, please revise to focus on that. You seem to be asking two things here.

Comment: Correction: Your SEO question makes three. Please see [ask] and revise to ask just one clear, focused question.

Comment: I can't add the JS file as an external file, WordPress intentionally doesn't show that particular JS file in the head. But I have added it as inline JS script in the head section on all pages. Now the script doesn't work.

Comment: The code is already in the question. Just added it to tell that the script is present in the head as inline js instead of external file and the script is not working, and the question is focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with JavaScript, specifically jQuery, since WordPress includes it. In this case, `data-splitting` is not a tag, it is an attribute, a custom one. Custom attributes are mainly used to access elements or place useful information in tags to make something happen on the website. It won't affect your SEO.

In case you don't have one, create a scripts folder (typically named "js") in your actual theme folder, and create a file there named as you wish, for example, scripts.js, and enqueue that script in your functions.php file.

In that scripts.js file, you can add something like this:

```js
(function( $ ) {
    $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');
})(jQuery);
```

**Edit**

I edited the above code because `$('document').ready(function() { })` is deprecated in jQuery, so I used the "modern" approach.

I didn't specify it, but in your functions.php file, if you created a scripts folder named "js" inside your theme folder, you have to enqueue this script as follows:

```php
wp_enqueue_script('exampleJS', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'js/example.js', array(), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'js/example.js'), true);
```

`filemtime` is a function that gets file's modification time, and will allow you to modify CSS and JS files and avoid issues related to caching, i.e. the website is not showing the last version of the styles and scripts. You must use filemtime in every file you enqueue.

Comment: I added this to the WordPress fuctions.php ```Add h.js for Headings Animation
 function enqueue_my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hjs', 'https://example.com/h.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_script' );

Comment: I can't make it to work. Is there no way to hard code into the WordPress?

Comment: You've suggested what's in the question. Obviously that's not the problem. That said, the question is unclear.

Comment: @isherwood, I did included the code of Carlos Talaver to my question later though edit. The question is about how to change <h2> tag on all pages in to <h2 data-splitting>. Carlos Talaver suggested creating a .js file and enqueue it. But it can't be added to the head section as an external .js file. I can only add it to the head as inline js script but it didn't change the h1 tags.

Comment: The answer is updated now. Sorry for taking so long, but I hadn't visited StackOverflow for a while and I got no email notifications.